# Can I get an XML files structure without looking up the element names myself?

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

Using PHP, I would like to be able to open an XML file and get its structure without having to know any about the structure already. Is this possible?

I've been using XMLReader up until now but I'm parsing a wide variety of structures so it takes a while to go through each file manually and identify the structure.

I would only need to open the first parent node as every node after that would be the same.

e.g.

```
<name>
<first></first>
<second></second>
</name>
```

I would like to be able to identify this structure without having to manually look at the file first.

Happy to use other libraries than XMLReader but would need to stick with PHP.

Thanks!

Comment: Might you be talking about [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by identify? Of course you can read elementnames, but is that what you really need?

Comment: If there's a nice DTD or XSD to go with the XML, then yes! But many XML files these days don't reference any definition file for their structure, they're just "ad hoc" put together as something that looks XMLish

Answer (score 1):

`DOMDocument` should be able to do it.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($xml_data);
/* @var $names DOMNodeList */
$names = $dom->getElementsByTagName('name');
for($i=0;$i<$names->length;$i++){
    $node = $names->item($i);
    if($node->nodeName=='first'){
        $first_name = $node->nodeValue;  // store this
    }elseif($node->nodeName=='second'){
        $second_name = $node->nodeValue; // store this
    }
}
```

**Make sure that they are valid XML files.**